# CarrierWave not storing url for uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, background-process, sidekiq

I am trying to process my uploaded images (with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)) in the background (through [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)).

Here is my configuration ([carrierwave_delay gem](https://github.com/slooob/carrierwave-delay)):

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    def is_processing_delayed? img = nil
        !! @is_processing_delayed
    end

    def is_processing_immediate? img = nil
        ! is_processing_delayed?
    end

    def is_processing_delayed= value
        @is_processing_delayed = value
    end

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    storage :fog

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    process resize_to_fill: [500, 500]
    version :large, if: :is_processing_delayed? do
        process resize_to_fill: [192, 192]
    end
    version :medium, from: :large, if: :is_processing_delayed? do
        process resize_to_fill: [144, 144]
    end

    def extension_whitelist
        %w(png)
    end

end

class App < ApplicationRecord

    mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader

    carrierwave_delay [:icon]

    cattr_accessor :carrierwave_delay_columns

    def self.carrierwave_delay columns
        after_save :carrierwave_delay_process
        self.carrierwave_delay_columns = columns
    end

    def self.carrierwave_delay_queue
        :default
    end
    def self.carrierwave_delay_priority
        20
    end

    def recreate_delayed_versions!
        self.class.carrierwave_delay_columns.each do |column|
            unless self.send(column).file.nil?
                self.send(column).is_processing_delayed = true
                self.send(column).recreate_versions!
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def carrierwave_delay_process
        self.delay(queue: self.class.carrierwave_delay_queue, priority: self.class.carrierwave_delay_priority, retry: false).recreate_delayed_versions!
    end

end
```

---

All files get processed successfully and get stored on S3, as configured in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`. But unfortunately the `icon.send(version).url` method remains returning `nil` (thus does not get updated after a file got uploaded successfully).

*Regular uploading works well.*

Comment: Just curious why you are implementing the methods `is_processing_delayed?` abd `is_processing_immediate?`

Comment: @ErnestSim I followed a [blog post](http://code.dblock.org/2011/09/22/carrierwave-delayjob-processing-of-selected-versions.html) building this.

Comment: You are doing it hard way, this tutorial is too old, try to use the official instructions for gem

Comment: @kolas And where are the official instructions for this case?

Comment: I was wrong, i think this gem does not work with fog

Comment: @kolas It does. As I mentioned in the question, files get uploaded successfully.

Comment: Well, you are trying to reinvent something that is widely used already, drop old tutorials and your own gem and try it with `carrierwave_backgrounder` or similar. BTW, this is getting overly verbose, try to reduce stuff that need to be explicitly declared and incorporate common methods on the gem itself.

Comment: @ErvalhouS The problem with `carrierwave_backgrounder` is that it processes in the cloud and not the worker itself. This gets fairly expensive pretty quickly.

Comment: @ErvalhouS I did use `carrierwave_backgrounder` with AWS before I decided to write my own solution and got billed for my usage of AWS' processing resources (I always forget the name)

Comment: @ErvalhouS Please explain why. By billed I don't mean billed for storage, GET or POST requests.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No I didn't. In the end, I switched from AWS to Digital Ocean. They did not bill me for processing resources.